# SpeechRecognition API does not work on android chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, nuxt.js, speech-recognition

I am working on implementing voice detection during user recordings using the SpeechRecognition API in a Nuxt.js 2 project. The functionality is working perfectly on desktop Chrome, and I have confirmed that my website is using HTTPS. I have also verified that the sound is being recorded correctly. However, when I attempted to debug the code on a mobile device, I noticed that the 'onsoundstart' event is not being triggered, unlike what I observe on my desktop. Can anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to address this issue? I kept getting null in my result (textTranscript);

```
startRecording() {
    this.durationSpeak = this.questionData?.duration_speaking;
    navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
        .then((stream) => {
            this.stream = stream;                         
            this.recorder = RecordRTC(stream, {
                type: "audio",
                mimeType: "audio/mp3",
            });  
            this.recorder.startRecording();
            const SpeechRecognition = window.speechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
            this.recognization = new SpeechRecognition();
            this.recognization.continuous = true;
            this.recognization.interimResults = false;
            this.recognization.lang = "en-US";
            this.recognization.addEventListener("result", (e) => {
                const result = Array.from(e.results)
                    .map((result) => result[0])
                    .map((result) => result.transcript)
                    .join("");
                this.$emit('updateUserAns', {
                    index: this.currentPage - 1,
                    question_id: this.questionData?.id,
                    textTranscript: result,                            
                });
            });
            this.recognization.start();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // this.$sentry.captureException(error);
            console.error("Error getting media stream:", error);
        });    
        this.countDownSpeak();
},
```